# 'How long' - (duration of an activity) for past simple continuous

Tags: past-tense

'How long' for sentences in the past simple continuous to talk about the duration of an activity in the past?

- How long did it rain last night?

   - It rained for about 3 hours.
- How long did he study yesterday?

   - He studied for six hours.

I know that we can use the duration with simple past tense to talk about
the completion of an activity in a sequence.
However, in the past simple continuous,

- How long was he studying this time yesterday?

   - He was studying for six hours.

can we use past simple and past simple continuous in some sort of ***interchangeably***?

As we are not talking about an activity that went on up to that time, in this case, we use past perfect, but we are talking about the sequence of actions. For example, 
Yesterday, I went to a restaurant. And *I waited for my friends for an hour/ I was waiting for my friends for an hour*, but none of them came, so went back home.

I think it's just about nuances. Using a simple emphasis on the completion and continuous emphasis on the ongoing activity.

Comment: Yes. Note that "for" can be added, as in "For how long did it rain last night?, or How long did it rain for last night?

Comment: Note idiomatic [*"**How long is a piece of string**?"*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22How+long+is+a+piece+of+string%22) used as a dismissive response to an "imprecise" badly-posed question (until you specify ***which*** piece of string, the length is indeterminate).

Comment: The third sentence doesn't work because _this time yesterday_ refers to a fixed point in time.

Comment: I'm not sure what meaning is intended by the third example. I suspect it intends something like "How long *had he been studying for by* this time yesterday," but please edit to make it clear. There's nothing wrong with the other two, but please edit to tell more about why you had doubts about them.

Comment: @AndyBonner I wanted to know if we can use duration with past simple continuous. If yes, what's the difference between this past simple continuous with duration and Past perfect continuous? For example, *he was studying for 3 hours yesterday.* and *he had been studying for 3 hours yesterday.*, and I know that past perfect continuous can only be used when the particular time around which we are talking is clear, so I just wanted to know the difference.

Comment: Comments aren't official, permanent parts of the question. Please use the "edit" button below the question to make sure it's clear and has all the information it needs. I'm still not sure what the central question really is.

Comment: @AndyBonner edited

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you often use **how long** to ask questions about duration of time. It can be used to ask questions about the past, present and future. You can clarify when you're asking about, or leave it up to the context of the discussion. Your examples are correct, except for the last one:

> How long did it rain?
> How long did it rain last night?
> How long did he study?
> How long did he study yesterday?
> How long was he studying <s>this time</s> yesterday?

Other examples:

> How long is the movie?
> How long have you been sitting here?
> How long will you be in California?
> How long will you have been married on December 31?

Note that it can also be used to ask about an object's *length*, for example:

> How long is a yardstick?